# Aligning output data under various columns in a listbox

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I got the results I needed from the Listview control. Now I would like to export the data to a text file/excel and then load it back to the listview control when I need to. I know how to do both these tasks using the listbox control but listview is new to me. I've been researching and playing around with code for hours but I keep getting one error or the other. Kindly find the latest version of my code to export data below. Also, if you could provide code to import, that would be super.

```
'Export the listview to an Excel spreadsheet

 Dim SaveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog
 SaveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Excel File"
 SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls|Excel Files 
 (*.xlsx)|*.xslx"
 SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    'exit if no file selected
  If SaveFileDialog1.FileName = "" Then
   Exit Sub
  End If

   'create objects to interface to Excel
 Dim xls As New Excel.Application
 Dim book As Excel.Workbook
 Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim placeholder As String

 'create a workbook and get reference to first worksheet
 xls.Workbooks.Add()
 book = xls.ActiveWorkbook
 sheet = book.ActiveSheet

 'step through rows and columns and copy data to worksheet

    Dim row As Integer = 1
    Dim col As Integer = 1

    For Each item As ListViewItem In lstViewUsers.Items
        For i As Integer = 0 To item.SubItems.Count - 1
            placeholder = sheet.Cells(row, col) = item.SubItems(i).Text
            col = col + 1
        Next
        row += 1
        col = 1
    Next

    'save the workbook and clean up

    book.SaveAs(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
    xls.Workbooks.Close()
    xls.Quit()



End Sub
```

Comment: Would you consider using a `ListView` or `DataGridView`?

Comment: A ListBox can set *hard* (pixel positions) tab stops, but it's not worth it. Use a ListView in Details view, add the Columns needed to present your data.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are trying to align the text by the number of character, that will work only if all character have same width, but it's not, for example WWWW is larger than IIII, so you have to think in pixel that will be more correct than text .length. so as said previously better use DataGridView it will save your time.

Comment: If you want to align text based on characters then you have to use a fixed-width font. Also, the way you're doing it is dodgy. Read [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?530270).

Comment: I used the ListView and it worked perfectly. Thanks guys! You're awesome!

Comment: @AndrewMortimer, so after getting the results I wanted from the Listview control, I'm faced with the task of exporting this data to a text file/excel and then loading it back to the listview control when I need to. I know how to do both these tasks using the listbox control but listview is new to me. I've been researching and playing around with code for hours but I keep getting one error or the other. Kindly find the latest version of my code to export data in the modified question above. Also, if you could provide code to import, that would be super!. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Generally it is best to leave the original question as it was, and ask a completely new question with your new issue.